# Racket: filtering with two conditions (turning columns into lists)

Tags: list, matrix, filter, racket, abstraction

I'm trying to create a list containing all the values of a column from lists of lists resembling a matrix.
The list should contain only numbers and guess-number of a

```scm
(define-struct guess (symbol number))
```

puzzle1:

```scm
 (list
    (list 'a 'b 'b 'c)
    (list 'a 2 1 4)
    (list 'f 3 'g 'g)
    (list 'f 'h 'i 'i))
```

The parameters are the matrix and a position, so:

```scm
(check-expect (used-in-column puzzle1 (make-posn 0 1)) (list 2 3))

(define-struct puzzle (size board constraints))
```

where the board part is the puzzle1 example needed above

I can create a list with only the numbers, but seem unable to alter the code so it adds any guess-number to the list

so here's an example with a guess inside of it, where the output given by my code is empty

```scm
(check-expect (used-in-column puzzle1partial2 (make-posn 0 1)) (list 2))
```

Where the puzzle-board is

```scm
(list
    (list (make-guess 'a 2) 'b 'b 'c)
    (list 'a 2 1 4)
    (list 'f 3 'g 'g)
    (list 'f 'h 'i 'i))
```

So far my code looks like this:

```scm
(define (used-in-column puz pos)
  (local [(define (columns board pos)
            (cond
              [(empty? board) empty]
              [else (cons  (list-ref (first board) (posn-x pos))
                           (columns (rest board) pos))]))]
    (cond    
      [(empty? puz) empty?]
      [else (quicksort (filter number? (columns (puzzle-board puz) pos)) <)])))
```

I tried using if statements and other variants, but it ends up making my code a mess and not getting me any results.

Can anybody give me any advice on this?

Comment: I can't run this. You forgot to add the struct `posn`.

Answer (score 2):

As for you subject you can transpose with the standard `unzip`:

```scm
(define (unzip lsts)
  (apply map list lsts))

(unzip '((1 2) (a b))) ; ==> ((1 a) (2 b))
```

If you just want one row you use list-ref:

```scm
(map (lambda (x) (list-ref x 1)) '((1 2) (a b))) ; ==> (2 b)
```

I really don't understand what your code is supposed to do and I can't run it either (lacks a stuct I think) so I leave it at this.